# Angular change the background colour of the active mat-tab from code

Tags: angular, angular-material, scss-mixins, mat-tab

Good morning,
I have an Angular page that contains tabs made with Mat Tab.
I managed to set the background colour of the active tab via scss with the following code and everything works correctly:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
background-color: var(--user-main-color);
font-weight: 900;}
```

But now I would like to customise the colour dynamically, taking it via a REST call to the backend where the colour configuration is set.
how can i do this?
I thought of using [style.background-colour]="variable-name" but I don't understand how it can be done only for the active tab.
thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-tab.mdc-tab--active{
  background-color: green !important;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

UPDATE:

if you want change styles in typescript try this:

ts:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.changeBackgroundColor();
    
  }
  changeActiveTab(): void {
    this.removePreviousActiveTabClass();
    this.changeBackgroundColor();
  }

  changeBackgroundColor(): void {
    const activeTab = document.getElementsByClassName('mdc-tab--active')[0];    
    (activeTab as HTMLElement).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    (activeTab as HTMLElement).classList.add('active-tab');
  }

  removePreviousActiveTabClass(): void {
    const previousActiveTab = document.getElementsByClassName('active-tab')[0];
    (previousActiveTab as HTMLElement).style.backgroundColor = 'unset';
    previousActiveTab.classList.remove('active-tab');
  }
```

in HTML file:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="changeActiveTab()">
   <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

in angular material 15 and later this code should work.
in previous versions i think you have to replace (mdc-tab--active) class with your classes.

Comment: I need to set color dynamic runtime in typescript before a rest Call.

Comment: To change dynamically the label text color, you can use tab-active with tab mixins called `active-text-label-color`

 .mdc-tab.mdc-tab--active{
    @include tab-mixins.active-text-label-color(map.get($foreground-palette, text));
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab.mdc-tab.mdc-tab.mdc-tab--active {
  background-color: var(--user-main-color);
  font-weight: 900;
}
```